# sql-server-2008 : get the last status of subjects of a student

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

Salam, (Greetings) to all.

**Intro:** 
I am working on a Student Examination System, where Students appear and pass or fail or absent.

**Problem:** 
I am tasked to fetch their Summary of Status. you may say a Result Card which should print their very last status of a Subject.

Below is a sample of the data where a student has appeared many times, in different sessions. I have highlighted one subject in which a student has appeared three times.

[image]

Now, I write the following Query which extract the same result as the picture above:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
gr.STUDKEY,gr.SUBJECT_ID, gr.SUBJECT_DESC,gr.MARKS, 
gr.PASSFAIL, gr.GRADE,max(gr.SESSION_ID), gr.LEVEL_ID

FROM RESULT gr

WHERE gr.STUDKEY = '0100106524'
GROUP BY gr.STUDKEY,gr.SUBJECT_ID, gr.SUBJECT_DESC,gr.MARKS,  
gr.PASSFAIL, gr.GRADE, gr.LEVEL_ID
```

**Desired:** 
I want to get only the last status of a subject in which a student has appeared.

Help is requested. Thanks in advanced.

Regards

**I am using sql-server-2008.**

Comment: Why SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Is there a date field or datetime field?  order by your date in descending order, and specify "TOP 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work because you include fields like gr.MARKS and gr.GRADE in the group by and in the select which means that the query might return more than 1 record for each session id while their grade or marks is different.

```
SELECT 
gr.STUDKEY,gr.SUBJECT_ID, gr.SUBJECT_DESC, 
gr.PASSFAIL, gr.GRADE,gr.SESSION_ID, gr.LEVEL_ID
FROM RESULT gr 
JOIN (SELECT MAX(SessionId) as sessionId, STUDKEY 
      FROM RESULT 
      GROUP BY  STUDKEY ) gr1 ON gr1.sessionId=gr.sessionid AND gr1.STUDKEY =gr.STUDKEY
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully there is a date field, or something that indicates the order of the students appearances in this class. Use that to order your query in descending order, so that the most recent occurrence is the first record, then specifiy "Top 1" which will then give you only the most recent record for that student, which will include in his most recent status.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
gr.STUDKEY,gr.SUBJECT_ID, gr.SUBJECT_DESC,gr.MARKS, 
gr.PASSFAIL, gr.GRADE,gr.SESSION_ID, gr.LEVEL_ID
FROM RESULT gr
WHERE gr.STUDKEY = '0100106524'
ORDER BY gr.Date DESC  //swap "Date" out for your field indicating the sequence.
```

or use a Group by with MAX(Date) if you're looking for multiple classes with the same student at the same time.